# How can I "center" the child elements of this variable-width menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

Here's a Codepen link that displays what I have so far:
http://codepen.io/alih/pen/xijbm

Edited: Here's a new Codepen link, with the nested divs replaced with list items & uls. I welcome suggestions for how to do this without extraneous mark-up, but my major concern remains how to center the Drop-down panel against the borders reaching up to the menu above it.
http://codepen.io/alih/pen/KzsAc

---

I am building a drop-down menu with the following features:

- Multiple levels, but only one level of drop-down. Child lists will be displayed inline immediately beneath their parent elements.
- The parent level of the menu will be list items of variable width
- The drop-down lists will have a background on them that is always the same width
- The drop-down lists will appear to be "connected" to the parent element with "ropes" that connect to the left and right edges of the top level menu items.
- And here is the bit I am having trouble with: the background on the drop-down list will be centered against these "ropes". On the Codepen demo, this means that the green & grey panel will be centered against the borders "connecting" the panel to the list item above.

This menu needs to work as far back as IE7, and while I may make flagrant use of extraneous divs to achieve my goal, I may not use JavaScript (which is normally how I would solve this: subtract the width of the parent item from the width of the drop-down and add a negative margin of that amount to the drop-down).

What I want to know is: is there any way this is possible using HTML & CSS alone?

My CSS (Edited):

```
.other {
  float:left
}

ul#topnav,
ul#topnav li,
ul#topnav ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}


#topnavblock {
    background:grey;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
  z-index:700;
}

#topnav {
  z-index:2;
}

#topnav > li > a {
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
}

#topnav li a:hover {
    color: #444;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #ffffff;
}

#topnav [class^="current"] {
    background: lightyellow;
}


#topnav li a {
    color: #893200;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 25px 5px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
    font: bold 14px 'Arvo', serif;
}


#topnav [class^="current"] > a {
    color: #FF6600;
}
#topnav [class^="current"] > a:hover {
    color: #FF6600;
}

ul#topnav {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 597;
 float: left;
 left:20px;
 padding: 0;
}


ul#topnav > li {
 float: left;
 min-height: 1px;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

ul#topnav > li {
 padding:10px 0 14px 0;
}


ul#topnav li.hover,
ul#topnav li:hover {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 599;
 cursor: default;
}

ul#topnav ul {
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 598;
 width: 100%;
}

ul#topnav li .navwrap1 {
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: -23px;
  padding-top: 23px;
  width: 210px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}

ul#topnav li .navwrap2 {
  background:grey;
  padding-bottom: 33px;
}

ul#topnav > li > ul {
border-right: 3px solid grey;
  margin-top: -11px;
  margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}

ul#topnav ul .navwrap3 {
border-left:3px solid grey;
padding-top:60px;
}

ul#topnav .navwrap2 li {
 float: none;
 background:lightgreen;
 width:100%;
}

ul#topnav ul ul {
position:relative;
 top: 1px;
 left: 0;
}

ul#topnav ul li a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
}

ul#topnav ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 20px;
}

ul#topnav ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left:20px;
}

ul#topnav li:hover ul {
 visibility: visible;
}
```

My mark-up (abbreviated, the whole menu is visible at the CodePen link above):

```
<div id="topnavblock">
<ul id="topnav">   
<li><a href="#">Here is a menu item</a>
<ul>
  <li class="navwrap4">
    <ul class="navwrap3">
      <li class="navwrap1">
        <ul class="navwrap2">
          <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another menu item of a different length</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 2</a>
                <ul>
                  <li>Third level nested menu</li>
                  <li>This also has a child of different length</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 3</a></li>
        </ul><!--end navwrap2-->
      </li> <!--end navwrap1-->
    </ul><!--end navwrap3-->
  </li><!--end navwrap4-->
</ul>  
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item</a>
 <ul>
  <li class="navwrap4">
    <ul class="navwrap3">
      <li class="navwrap1">
        <ul class="navwrap2">
          <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 3</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-menu 3</a></li>
        </ul><!--end navwrap2-->
      </li> <!--end navwrap1-->
    </ul><!--end navwrap3-->
  </li><!--end navwrap4-->
</ul>  
</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: you do know that putting divs as direct childs of ul is invalid html code

Comment: Is it equally invalid to put any other block-level descendant inside of a UL? If you can suggest how to achieve the effect that I am after (described in detail above) without invalid mark-up, I would be happy to replace my invalid code with something better. --> Editing comment to say: thank you for the reminder, but right now I am more concerned with the possible than the valid. I will need another approach entirely if I can't center the child list anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For `ul#topnav li .navwrap1` change `margin-top: -23px;` to `margin: -23px auto 0;`. That will center that element.